# Building jars properly with sbt

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jar, sbt

I have a map reduce `.scala` file like this:

```
import org.apache.spark._

object WordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val inputDir = args(0)
    //val inputDir = "/Users/eksi/Desktop/sherlock.txt"
    val outputDir = args(1)
    //val outputDir = "/Users/eksi/Desktop/out.txt"
    val cnf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Example MapReduce Spark Job")

    val sc = new SparkContext(cnf)

    val textFile = sc.textFile(inputDir)
    val counts = textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
      .map(word => (word, 1))
      .reduceByKey(_ + _)
    counts.saveAsTextFile(outputDir)
    sc.stop()

  }
}
```

When I run my code, with `setMaster("local[1]")` parameters it works fine.

I want to put this code in a `.jar` and throw it to S3 to work with AWS EMR. Therefore, I use the following `build.sbt` to do so.

```
name := "word-count"

version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

// additional libraries
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.0.2"
)
```

It generates a jar file, however none of my scala code is in there. What I see is just a manifest file when I extract the `.jar`

When I run `sbt package` this is what I get:

```
[myMacBook-Pro] > sbt package
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/lele/bigdata/wordcount/project
[info] Set current project to word-count (in build file:/Users/lele/bigdata/wordcount/)
[info] Packaging /Users/lele/bigdata/wordcount/target/scala-2.11/word-count_2.11-0.0.1.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jul 27, 2016 10:33:26 PM
```

What should I do to create a proper jar file that works like

WordCount.jar WordCount

Comment: How are you creating the jar?

Comment: By calling `sbt clean compile package` from the terminal where `build.sbt` lives

Comment: And you don't see the your object `WordCount`? Weird, I'd expect you'd only see that without the `spark-core` dependency. Have you looked at the `sbt package` build log? Anything special?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I've updated my question, added build log. I noticed something funny, it took 0 seconds this time. I'm sure that it was not 0 before (`sbt clean compile package`)

Comment: Unrelated directly to your problem, but why are you mixing different scala versions? `scalaVersion` is set to 2.11.7 while your dependency is cross versioned to `_2.10`. You should use `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.0.2"` instead.

Comment: @giladhoch I know! When I change to `"spark-core"` or `_2.11` my build desperately fails! with `[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11;1.0.2: not found`

Comment: So either find another version of the library that is cross versioned to 2.11 or have your project written in 2.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref: *It generates a jar file, however none of my scala code is in there. What I see is just a manifest file when I extract the .jar*

Make sure your `WordCount.scala` is in the root or in `src/main/scala`

From http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Directories.html

> Source code can be placed in the project’s base directory as with hello/hw.scala. However, most people don’t do this for real projects; too much clutter.
>
> sbt uses the same directory structure as Maven for source files by default (all paths are relative to the base directory):

Comment: RTFM solution is the best solution. You are right, I messed up with directory structure. Merci!